# Overcoming Warning in NetBeans - PHP - Do not use Superglobals Array directly $_GET

Tags: php, netbeans, superglobals

I have some  lines of code like this;

A.

```
    if ( isset($_GET["logout"]) && $_GET["logout"] == 1){
    do_something;
    }
```

I replace with ( to get rid of the warning) ;

B.

```
    if ( isset( filter_input(INPUT_GET,'logout',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)  ) &&  
    filter_input(INPUT_GET,'logout',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) == 1){ 
    do_something;
    }
```

but i end up breaking the application with B. The login screen does not even appear. No error in the apache error log as well.

This is the sample url;

```
 http://192.168.0.91/test-app/?logout=1
```

What is wrong with my B. syntax/code? I guess i am using filter_input wrongly?

Update1:

php version ->php5-5.4.20-34.3.x86_64
netbeans version -> 8.0.1

Comment: i am running netbeans 8.0.1

Answer (score 1):

1. There is nothing wrong with A. Disable the hint in Netbeans, or ignore it.
2. No, there is nothing wrong with B. `filter_input` returns `null` if the key does not exist, and `isset` will return `false` if the condition is `null`, so your logic is fine and the usage of the function is too. The only problem might be that your PHP version is too old. filter_input was introduced in 5.2.0.

Comment: Php version is 5.4x -> php5-5.4.20-34.3.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

Code B. was fixed by changing to ;

```
if ( filter_input(INPUT_GET,"logout",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) !== null &&    
filter_input(INPUT_GET,"logout",FILTER_SANITIZE_INT)==1) { 
dosomething;
}
```

Application runs fine now.

The inspiration for this fix is a fantastic article at http://kunststube.net/isset/ by David Zentgraf.
Wish there was a way to contact him to thank him but ... apparently he is a regular here.

Thanx Bro :)